# how to remove and add a button from the screen without affecting other buttons?

Tags: android, button

I'm dynamically creating buttons and place them randomly on the screen. I want to remove a button when it's being clicked and create another one, but when I do that, all the other buttons (the ones bellow him to be percise) also change their position (moving up 1 row). How can I modify my code so that the other buttons wont change their position when I click a button? I want to add the new button in the same row of the one that was removed.
I'm using a Linear Layout, so when I add a button it adds it to the bottom and fill the blank row by pushing up all the rows.

In the following code I just remove the button after a few seconds:

```
private void createGreenButton() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int hideDelay = r.nextInt(1000) + 1000;
    final Button greenButton = new Button(this);
    greenButton.setText("button");
    greenButton.setOnClickListener(greenButtonClick(greenButton));
    layout.addView(greenButton, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Place the buttons randomly on the screen
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Random r = new Random();

                    layout.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) greenButton
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    int horizontalMargin = r.nextInt(SCREEN_WIDTH
                            - greenButton.getWidth());
                    layoutParams.setMargins(horizontalMargin, 50, 0, 0);
                    greenButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    greenButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
    layout.requestLayout();

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ((ViewManager) greenButton.getParent()).removeView(greenButton);
            createGreenButton();
        }
    }, hideDelay);
}
```

Comment: Just make it invisible and remove the click listener. Something like `button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: The thing is that invisible still take space on the screen, so even after the button is invisible, adding another button is inserted to the bottom of the screen, thus, exceeding from the boundaries of the screen and finally I get a blank screen with buttons out of range...

Comment: Well there is also a 'button.setVisibility(View.GONE)'